# How to resolve locales dependency on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, dependencies

```
sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
 libc6:i386 : Recommends: libc6-i686:i386
              Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.


sudo apt-cache policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-12
  Candidate: 2.19-12
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-12 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.15-0ubuntu10.7 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.15-0ubuntu10 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages

sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  locales
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1655 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,916 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,282 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  locales
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of locales:
 libc6:i386 (2.19-12) breaks locales (<< 2.19) and is installed.
  Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20120306-3.
 libc6 (2.19-12) breaks locales (<< 2.19) and is installed.
  Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20120306-3.
dpkg: error processing locales (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 locales
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

sudo dpkg --configure -a  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of locales:  libc6:i386 (2.19-12) breaks locales (<<
2.19) and is installed.   Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20120306-3.  libc6 (2.19-12) breaks locales (<< 2.19) and is installed.   Version of locales to be configured is
2.13+git20120306-3. dpkg: error processing locales (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing:  locales
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Yes I did, see above

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate of the above issue, this is quite different

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` what happens?

Comment: I get the same error, see bug description.

Comment: Appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem 'packages have unmet dependencies' and the only solution that worked for me is to purge and reinstall all the unmet dependencies and their parents.

Comment: This is libc6, how do I purge that wont the system go for a toss

Comment: @Rpj may be `sudo apt-get purge libc6` first.

Comment: @Rpj not sure about that though, sorry!

Comment: purge libc6 is pretty dangerous.  may break everything else